# How to animate an element along an SVG path using only CSS and Scroll-driven Animations?

Tags: html, css, svg, scroll, css-animations

I am experimenting with Chrome Canary, and I have the following code which defines an SVG path and an image element. I would like to animate the image as I scroll, along the SVG path. How do I achieve this using only CSS and scroll-driven animations (without JavaScript)?

```css
#car {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<img id="car" width="256" height="256" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
<svg width="175" height="1300" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 175 1300" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path id="my_path"
        d="M 28 0 C -72 200 188 300 88 500 C -32 700 88 1100 148 1000 C 208 900 148 600 68 1000 C 28 1200 128 1300 128 1300"
        stroke-width="4" stroke="#000" />
</svg>
```

Comment: why are you repeating the same answer you added in another question?

Comment: While I shared a preview of the scroll-driven animation code in an answer to a different question, that question wasn't relevant to those specifically experimenting with Chrome Canary and scroll-driven animations. Most of my answer in that question was directed towards the OP's particular case, which required the use of JavaScript and non-experimental features. However, I intentionally phrased this question about the new, emerging CSS spec on Scroll-driven Animations, to separate it from JavaScript implementations.

Comment: Write your blogs on Dev.to (Medium is mostly behind a pay-wall) You will get more upvotes.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Thanks for the tip, but is SO not still developers' go-to resource for copying code? Personally, I check this website for potential quick solutions before I start researching more long-winded blog posts. I don't necessarily care about the votes, I just want this information quickly accessible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Note: This currently only works in Chrome Canary 115+ with `experimental-web-platform-features` enabled.**

In general, the strategy is to use the `offset-path` style property with the `url()` CSS function to reference the path the element should follow. In this case specifically, you would set it to `url(#my_path)`. And then in your `@keyframes <name>`, simply transition from `offset-distance: 0%;` to `offset-distance: 100%;`.

However, the method of attaching a scroll-driven timeline to your animation depends largely on the structure of your page and precisely where the path is located on the page. Namely, there are two cases.

**Case 1: The path spans the entire scroll container**

This is the simple case. We can associate a scroll timeline with the animation using `animation-timeline: scroll();`, which references the block axis of the nearest ancestor scroll container. And then we set the animation on the element using `animation: <name> linear;`.

Make sure to also set the initial position of the element to `(0,0)` of the offset parent via `position: absolute` and `inset: 0`. All together, the code should look something like this:

```css
#car {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  
  offset-path: url(#my_path);
  animation: offsetDistance linear;
  animation-timeline: scroll();
}

@keyframes offsetDistance {
    from { offset-distance: 0%; }
    to { offset-distance: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<img id="car" width="256" height="256" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
<svg width="175" height="1300" viewBox="0 0 175 1300" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path id="my_path" d="M 28 0 C -72 200 188 300 88 500 C -32 700 88 1100 148 1000 C 208 900 148 600 68 1000 C 28 1200 128 1300 128 1300"
        stroke-width="4" stroke="#000" />
</svg>
```

**Case 2: The path is a portion of the scroll container**

In this case, we must use a [View Progress Timeline](https://www.w3.org/TR/scroll-animations-1/#view-timelines) which requires a little more effort to setup correctly, and so it's easier to explain step-by-step.

1. Declare a scope on the nearest common ancestor of the element and the path. This enables the attachment of a view timeline to be deferred to a descendent, which will be the path element, and referenced by other decendents, which will be the image element.

```css
#container {
  timeline-scope: --container;
}
```

2. Attach the path element to the view timeline with the same name, like so:

```css
#my_path {
  view-timeline-name: --container;
}
```

3. Associate the named timeline with the element's animation.

```css
#car {
  animation-timeline: --container; /* ... */
}
```

4. Determine your animation's timeline range. This also depends greatly on your page's structure and likely requires some manual testing. However, [this tool](https://scroll-driven-animations.style/tools/view-timeline/ranges/) is extremely helpful in understanding the behavior of various ranges. In my example, I choose the following:

```css
#car {
  animation-timeline: --container; 
  animation-range: exit-crossing -5% entry-crossing 105%;
  /* ... */
}
```

5. Lastly, to prevent visual glitches at the end of the animation, change the `animation-fill-mode` to `forwards`.

```css
#car {
  animation: <name> linear forwards;
  animation-timeline: --container; 
  animation-range: exit-crossing -5% entry-crossing 105%;
  /* ... */
}
```

Finally, putting everything together, we get the following animation:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  timeline-scope: --container;
}

#my_path {
  view-timeline-name: --container;
}

#car {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;

  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;

  offset-path: url(#my_path);
  animation: offsetDistance linear forwards;
  animation-timeline: --container;
  animation-range: exit-crossing -5% entry-crossing 105%;
}

@keyframes offsetDistance {
  from { offset-distance: 0%; }
  to { offset-distance: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 150px;"></div>
<div id="container">
    <img id="car" width="256" height="256"
        src="data:image/png;base64,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">
    <svg width="175" height="1300" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 175 1300" fill="none"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path id="my_path" d="M 28 0 C -72 200 188 300 88 500 C -32 700 88 1100 148 1000 C 208 900 148 600 68 1000 C 28 1200 128 1300 128 1300"
            stroke-width="4" stroke="#000" />
    </svg>
</div>
<div style="height: 150px;"></div>
```

Comment: [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). And since scroll-driven animations is a new, emerging CSS proposal, I wanted to contribute information that isn't on SO yet, especially since this was something I was also stuck on.

Comment: Depends on the information and depth I'm willing to cover. In this case, I didn't want to discuss or explain Scroll-driven animations, there are already better articles for that. I just wanted to share what I believed was an elegant code snippet for a common problem. Perhaps I could have waited a little to give an answer, but SO provides the ability to post an answer with your question for a reason.

Comment: And sure this isn't relevant to most browsers or users yet, but there are people (like me) who are experimenting with Chrome Canary and future versions of other browsers now; this content is for them. And over time, this will only become more relevant to more people.